# Using regex to search until desired pattern

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics

I am using the following regex:

```
orfre = '^(?:...)*?((ATG)(...){%d,}?(?=(TAG|TAA|TGA)))' % (aa)
```

I basically want to find all sequences that start with ATG followed by triplets (e.g. TTA, TTC, GTC, etc.) until it finds a stop codon in frame. However, as my regex is written, it won't actually stop at a stop codon if aa is large. Instead, it will keep searching until it finds one such that the condition of aa is met. I would rather have it search the entire string until a stop codon is found. If a match isn't long enough (for a given aa argument) then it should return None.

String data:
AAAATGATGCATTAACCCTAATAA

Desired output from regex:
ATGATGCATTAA

Unless aa > 5, in which case nothing should be returned.

Actual output I'm getting: ATGATGCATTAACCCTAA

Comment: Provide your string data here.

Comment: Try one of the following `(ATG)([ACGT]{3})*?(TAG|TAA|TGA)` or `(ATG)((?!TAG|TAA|TGA)[ACGT]{3})+(TAG|TAA|TGA)`

Comment: @hwnd that could work, except that the regex is contained within a function that specifies the minimum number of amino acids

Comment: You could possibly adjust it to my expression.

Comment: This question was asked a few days ago, but it was deleted. What will happen with this one?

Comment: So the minimum number of amino acids specified by `aa` does not include the stop codon?

Comment: And you also don't want a match to have a start/stop codon in the middle, right? Otherwise ATGATGCATTAACCCTAA would be fine.
In that case you should change your `(...)` into `((?!(ATG|TAG|TAA|TGA))...)` to exclude them

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. [You can see it on codepad](http://codepad.org/RHLp6VVq).

```
import re

num = 4
blue = 'XXXAAAATGATGCATTAACCCTAATAAXXX'
pattern = "^(?:...)*(ATG(...){%d}(?:TAG|TAA|TGA))" % num

m = re.match(pattern, blue)
print m.group(1)
```

Which outputs: `ATGCATTAACCCTAATAA`

Breaking it down:

```
^
(?:...)*           - Find, but don't capture any number of triplets.
(                  - Begin our capture block
  ATG              - A literal string of 'ATG', no need to wrap.
  (...)*           - Any number of triplets
  (?:TAG|TAA|TGA)  - A non capturing block of either 'TAG', 'TAA' or 'TGA'
)                  - End the capture block.
```

Unless I'm missing some other requirements, it shouldn't need to be much more complex than this.

Answer (score 0):

**Supplementary note:** if you want to check the six frames available in one sequence, don't forget to check also the complementary chain:

```
comp_chain = chain[::-1]
```

(--> [extended slices](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html))

Transliterating latter A's for T's and G's for C's.